# How to print parameter in zimpl format file in lpsolve IDE?

Tags: scip

when run Zimpl format file in lpsolve IDE,

```
set d := { "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4" };
param P[d] :=<"d1"> 11, <"d2"> 22;
do print P;
```

display following errors:

> ````
> *** Error 142: Unknown index <> for symbol "P"
> *** do print P;
> ***           ^^^ ```
> ````

In the reference of Zimpl user guide, do print dosnot support parameter. How to print parameter in zimpl file?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the `do print` command doesn't support printing arrays.

Try

```
do forall <i> in d : print P[i];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  "do forall <i> in d do print P[i];" can run successfully under the ZIMPL v2.06. The multi lines display. How to display in one line?